# Rename .zip file generated by electron packager

Tags: electron, electron-packager

Electron-packager generates folder `my-app-win32-x64` but I want this file to be only my-app. I want rest to be removed. I understand electron packager generates .zip file. When this is unzipped it retains the same name.

I tried editing index.js under electron-packager. I am not able to understand this .zip file is generated. So that I can edit the name in which elctron-packager generates this file.

Directory structure:

```
my-app
/scripts
...
...
/win64
  /my-app-win32-x64   //this directory name must be just my-app
    my-app.exe
    /app
```

Build script:

```
"build": "electron-packager --out winx64 --overwrite --platform win32 --appname my-app . --icon=./my_logo.ico --executable-name my-app"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how this relates to any ZIP file at all. `electron-packager` creates a directory structure with an executable, folders, etc., but no ZIP file.

---

Electron-packager creates a directory `{out}/{appname}-win32-x64` where `{out}` and `{appname}` are the given command line parameters.

Since you want this output directory to have a different name, you could simply rename it after it's created.

**Linux/Mac:**

```
"build": "electron-packager ... &&    mv   win64/my-app-win32-x64  win64/my-app"
```

**Windows:**

```
"build": "electron-packager ... &&    ren  win64\my-app-win32-x64  win64\my-app"
```

The `&&` runs the second command only if the first one completes successfully (non-zero exit code).

Comment: Thats the simplest solution :)